# Binding only specific objects from ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an `ObservableCollection<Model>` which is filled with objects that are parsed from a text file. Every object is an individual line. When I bind that collection to a controller, a listbox for example I want to display just some specific lines, which have in their model a boolean property set to true. For example:

Model:

```
class Model
{
    public bool ShowText {get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding LinesCollection}"  <!-- A boolean property that will only display the objects whos ShowText is set to true -->   />
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Please specify the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WPF way to do this is to create a [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), set its [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.source%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to the observable collection, set a [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler that only accepts the items you are interested in and finally bind your `ListBox` to the `CollectionViewSource`.

There is a [detailed example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that shows how to do this with a datagrid, but the same concept applies to your situation as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Hold a "master" and a "view" list in your view model and bind to the "view" list. Whenever the master list is updated, the view list is updated in sync under whatever condition you have.
2. Use a converter on the list that filters the data for you. Your convert function would look something like:

   `return (value as IEnumerable).Where(l => somecondition);`

The binding becomes:

`{Binding Path=LinesCollection, Converter={StaticResource FilterConverter}}`

with a resource (xmlns namespace of local for your converter assumed):

`<local:FilterLinesConverter x:Key="FilterConverter"/>`

Comment: Not that much more complicated than any answer besides yours. This approach (and the others) is also more extensible for situations other than binding straight to a bool.

Comment: +1 No way, a valid solution deserved a -1 and I agree this is more extensible.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

Set the `ListBox`'s [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/) to bind to that property using a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
   </Window.Resources>

   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LinesCollection}">
      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ShowText, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
         </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ListBox>
</Window>
```

More complex way: Handle Filtering from the ViewModel by using an `ICollectionView`, as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @LordTakkera Setting `Visibility="Collapsed"` does not *remove* a UI element from the Visual Tree.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. You are hiding it and removing it from the layout.

Comment: `Visibility="Collapsed"` does not remove any element from the Visual Tree, however it does ensure templates are not applied and thus elements from the templates are not added to the `Visual Tree`

Answer (score 0):

Create another property which filters the data and returns a list whenever the main list is changed. Then bind to that.

```
public List<strings> TrueLines
{
   get { return LinesCollection.Where(ln => ln.ShowContent == true).ToList(); }
}


public List<Model> LinesCollection
{
   get { ... }
   set {  OnPropertyChanged("LinesCollection"); 
          OnPropertyChanged("TrueLines");
}
```

Xaml

```
<Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding TrueLines}"
```

### Update Thoughts

> ...objects that are parsed from a text file

Why are the objects in an observable collection if they are not changing? The above example adheres to that logic. If items are changing, then subscribe to the observable collection change notification and call `OnPropertyChanged("TrueLines");` during the event(s) which relate.

Comment: -1 This doesn't take into account that the `ObservableCollection` might not be changed but added/removed to.

Comment: @HighCore I don't believe that the OP needs an observable collection, and if that is the case then my post now accommodates for that situation.

Comment: Adding support for an observable collection is trivial, just add a handler to the collection changed event and have it notify property changed on "TrueLines". I believe this answer is just fine.

Comment: Each object is a model ( with a few string properties), which is an already parsed line. I just simplifed a question a bit.

Comment: @user3357962 I understand the *simplification* you mentioned, but is the real list (the one in the observable collection) one that has items being added to it after the initial load?